# Windows Phone 8 tiles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, tiles

i have recently started to develop apps for Windows Phone 8 after Windows Phone 7, the problem is with creating tiles, i am trying to use the simplest type (iconic tiles) just like we used to do in Windows Phone 7 opened the images from the assets and edited them from there, and modified the app manifest to select the images, but the tile is still showing white blank, i have searched deeply but there does not seem to be any tutorial about this

Comment: It might help to show some of your code that's setting this?

Comment: i do not know what is the code required !

Comment: have you modified all the tiles, by default you need to provide 2 the mid sized one and the small one? are they .png? are they set as build as Content? have you modified the manifest accordingly?

Comment: Open the manifest XML and post the icon part here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting your images to `Build Type` of `Content` and that they are actually being included in your xap.

For a complete discussion about Tiles start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Iconic Tiles cannot be colored. They are monochromatic. That is why you got blank white image.  The only shape on transparent background is used by Windows Phone to show such kind of tiles.
To get colored Tile you have to use Flip Template for it.